# How to change layout in the same activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have this activity (MapsActivity) which has a map fragment and a bottom sheet, everytime I click on a marker I want to show the details of that same marker in the screen, like the gif below:

[GIF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0sYkdWQO6iJUEJ6R0xZbWVzRE0)

Right now I'm making this by changing the activity on marker click, but I need to be able to do this in the same activity, I've read somethings about fragments and that it might be the best approach, can anyone point me in a direction?

Comment: you must use 2 fragments, 1 - map, 2 - changes after onclick of marker

Comment: How do I make the activity start with one and then change it to other?

Comment: Understan, There is Single Activity in which you have 2 fragments

Comment: Yes, in my MapsActivity I have a fragment (map) I want to replace that with the details fragment on marker click

Comment: yes that is the solution